# Validating a numeric input always returns a number as a value

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a piece of code that checks a numeric input. If the input is empty, then its value will be set to `0`. Later on, it will check if the input contains only numbers or if it contains other characters: it will then fire an alert and say if the input is valid (a number) or invalid (contains other characters).

Problem is, the input is always considered `0` even when I insert letters in the input field. If I remove the block that checks if the input is empty, the rest of the code works as intended.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the noob question.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const calculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

calculate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let inputValue = input.value;
  
  // Check if the input if empty; if it is, assign to it zero
  // Removing this if block will make everything else work fine
  if (inputValue === "") { // 
    inputValue = '0';
  } else { inputValue = inputValue; } //This line is useless, but will be implemented in a function so I kept it for debugging purposes
  
  // Check if the input contains only numbers
  let numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if ( inputValue.match(numbers) ) {
    alert(`Your input is valid. The number: ${inputValue}`)
  } else {
    alert(`Your input is not valid. The input: ${inputValue}`)
  }
  
});
```

```html
<h3>Insert a number or leave blank for Zero<h3>
<input type="number" id="input" placeholder="Insert number" style>
<input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using input type="number"

1. You will always get an empty string if the provided value is not a floating-point number.

   Ex. 12+ //"" empty
2. You will always get a floating-point number if you give input as valid floating-point number

   Ex. +12 // 12

   12 // 12

> The [value sanitization algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) is as follows: If the [value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-value)
> of the element is not a [valid floating-point number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-floating-point-number), then set it
> to the empty string instead.

By specifying the type (`<input type="number">`) you're asking the browser to only accept numbers. If you want to take non-numeric input and do something with it, you'd have to use (`<input type="text">`) and parse the content and do validation yourself.

So in your case

// Check if the input contains only numbers
code will never trigger if input taken by the user is not a [floating-point number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#value-sanitization-algorithm).

If you want to treat "" as 0:

```
const inputValue = +input.value;
   // 0          = "";
   // 12         = 12;
   // 12         = +12;
   // 0          = 12+ // since not a valid number
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the "input type=number" forces the browser to only accept numbers as valid values. Unfortunately, it seems to be a bug that other characters are also accepted: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1398528

If you change your input to type text, your code works.. Alas, that's not a good solution neither..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! How do other developers get around this bug though? I think I'll just leave the `type="number"` and hope that users won't be messing around with letters...